# Catch ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED in Node (try/catch does not work)

Tags: node.js

How do I best catch errors when using subprocess.send? In the following example, I run `node one.js` and get an uncaught `ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED` error, even though I'm using a try/catch.

```
// one.js
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const p = fork(require.resolve('./two.js'));
let exited = false;
p.on('exit', () => {
    console.log('Process exited');
    exited = true;
  });
setInterval(() => {
  if (!exited) {
    try {
      p.send('hello');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Ignore error');
    }
  }
}, 1);
```

```
// two.js
let count = 0;
process.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log(msg);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is asynchronous. The documentation is here: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback (perhaps you were looking at the `process.send` documentation?)

A fix would look like this:

```
// one.js
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const p = fork(require.resolve('./two.js'));
let exited = false;
setInterval(() => {
  if (!exited) {
    p.send('hello', undefined, undefined, (e) => {
      if (e !== null) {
        console.log('got err!', e);
        exited = true;
      }
    });
  }
}, 1);
```